# MySQL PDO - What is the best way to complete a request with a variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, pdo, sequence

What could the best way to complete such a request with MySQL PDO ?

It works fine in MySQL Workbench...

```
SET @sosa = 817595147;
SET @sequence = (SELECT REPLACE(seq, '-', ',') FROM lignee WHERE sosa = @sosa);

SELECT fullname_id, fullname
FROM fullname
WHERE FIND_IN_SET (fullname_id , @sequence)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET (fullname_id , @sequence) DESC
```

Then the result should be :

```
14354   DAILLY Gertrude (1068-1119)
13880   DE BELLOY Blanche (-)
13375   DE HORNOY Auguste (1121-1179)
...
532 LEPINGLE Eugène Alexandre (1909-1981)
531 LEPINGLE Raymonde Marie Emilie (1939-)
332 LHUILLIER Michel Eugène Maurice (1962-)
```

Note :

```
@sequence = '332-531-532-533-828-576-8471-10033-10389-10709-11503-11853-11959-12020-12070-12101-12135-12163-12185-12203-12264-12302-12355-12447-12603-12613-13019-13375-13880-14354'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

The first would be to launch separate queries to initialize your variables. However my preferred method is to set the variables in a join, like so.

```
SELECT a.fullname_id, a.fullname
FROM fullname as a
JOIN (SELECT @sosa := 817595147 as sosa) as b
JOIN (SELECT @sequence := (SELECT REPLACE(seq, '-', ',') FROM lignee WHERE sosa = @sosa) as sequence) as c
WHERE FIND_IN_SET (fullname_id , @sequence)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET (fullname_id , @sequence) DESC
```

Comment: That works fine !
I was also thinking about the separation of the queries, but your method using only one query is better for me, IMHO.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No probs! Good luck with your project